# Multiple objects from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two classes '`Product`' and '`Ingredient`'; In my view I have a '`Product`' object and I can create X '`Ingredient`' objects with javascript in a table.

How can I pass this `List<Ingredient>` from view to my controller and how should be the name of inputs of '`Ingredient`' if there's more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just post them back to then controller.

Their name in the query string should be in this format:

```
?Ingredient[0].Foo=bla1&Ingredient[0].Bar=bar1&Ingredient[1].Foo=foo2&Ingredient[1].Bar=bar2
```

and elements names in the HTML should be `Ingredient[x].property`

Comment: Nice, but I have this in my actionResult: public ActionResult Create(Product product,ICollection<Ingredient> ingredient), how can I use @Html.Editor() to be my ingredient parameter?

Comment: @murilokunze. You can't unless you write a custom template. google it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have done to accomplish this task. What you need to do is properly set the names of the controls to be in a array with correct index values. I use Jquery to set all the names before submit,
[Here is my example](http://codetuner.blogspot.com/2011/11/aspnet-mvc-submit-collection-of-models.html)